# mamp wordpress jquery problems. They aren't working

Tags: jquery, wordpress, mamp

My jQuery functions are firing but none of them are working through a vanilla wordpress install. Has anyone else had this problem?

To show an example of this would be quite challenging since it's running through a framework.

I have an external JS script called 'main.js':

```
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8"></script>
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/main.js" type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8"></script>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    foo1('.foo1',500);  

    $(".foo2").foo2({
        // foo2
    });
});

function foo1(e,s) {
    // foo1
}
```

It's normal setup an working when hosted. It's just on localhost that it isn't working for some reason. Is there a MAMP (OSX) setting that needs to be setup.

Comment: Can we see some example code, please?

Comment: Just added more info to the post. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The '$' sign does not work inside of wordpress by because of conflicting js libraries. Try using $.noConflict to address this problem by using the syntax below:

```
$.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

   foo1('.foo1',500);  

   $(".foo2").foo2({
    // foo2
   });

});
```